# Why does Ben Bradlee ask "Is anybody else tired of reading the news instead of reporting it"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-post

In *The Post* (2017), *The Times* publishes a story on obtaining the Pentagon Papers with news on the White House's cover-up stories. In a meeting of editors, managing editor Ben Bradlee asks a question:

> Ben Bradlee: **Is anybody else tired of reading the news instead of
>   reporting it?** Do we have any leads?

Why does he ask that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is pointing out that other news sources are getting stories before they do. That is how the people he's talking with are able to **read the news** (presumably in other newspapers), rather than finding leads themselves, uncovering stories, and **reporting the news** before other newspapers can.